# How to create multiple folders inside another folder using php?

Tags: php

Initially I created a folder whose name is coming from a SQL result which is stored in a variable after creating this folder I want to create two folders inside this folder.So below are the three lines which I have written for creating the folders.

```
mkdir($r,0777,true);  //Creating the first folder without any error
mkdir($r/'input',0777,true);  // not able to create the folder inside first folder
mkdir($r/'output',0777,true);  //not able to create the folder inside first folder
```

Comment: You need to edit your post to display the PHP code properly. try putting four spaces or a tab char in front of each line to see code formatting. Also, this doesn't look like vlalid code to me: mkdir($r/'input',0777,true);

Answer (score 0):

`$r/'input'` is not a valid path here. Actually it's not even a string, because you're doing arithmetic operation here. You need to put `/` into the string and concatenate it with `$r` using a dot:

```
$r . '/input'
```

The same for `output` folder.

Try to do:

```
mkdir($r,0777,true); 
mkdir($r . '/input',0777,true);  
mkdir($r . '/output',0777,true);
```